# Why the navigational properties are returned empty?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, entity-framework-6, navigation-properties

I have navigation property in the class. It has an association in the database but doesn't return data from **Employees** of type **Info** navigation property.

```
 public class Visa
    {
        public int VisaID { get; set; }
        public string VisaName { get; set; }
        public Info EmployeeInfo { get; set; }
        public List<Info> Employees { get; set; }
    }
```

Info class has 1 to many relationships with Visa class, also in the database.

```
 public class Info
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string FatherName { get; set; }
    }
```

In view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VisaName)

        </td>

            @foreach (var employee in item.Employees)
            {
               <td>@Html.DisplayFor(empItem => employee.Name) </td>
               <td>@Html.DisplayFor(empItem => employee.FatherName)</td>       
            }

        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.VisaID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.VisaID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.VisaID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

**item.Employees** are empty. Why? Even the tables have data in it.

Update:

Also, this is not working. So, overall the employees are getting returned empty for whatsoever reasons.

```
            InfoDBContext InfoContext = new InfoDBContext();

            object o = InfoContext.Visas.ToList().Where(visa => visa.VisaName == "Visa 1").FirstOrDefault().Employees;
            return View(o);
```

Update:

This isn't working too.

```
  public ActionResult VEmployees() 
        {
            InfoDBContext InfoContext = new InfoDBContext();
            //int EmployeeID = InfoContext.Infoes.ToList().Where(emp => emp.ID == 1).FirstOrDefault().ID;
            object o = InfoContext.Visas.Include(e => e.Employees).Where(v => v.VisaName=="Hunain").FirstOrDefault().Employees;
            return View(o);
        }
```

returns empty for both entities

Comment: These mixed associations should be mapped carefully. Please show your EF mappings.

Answer (score 1):

This probably happens because `Employees` are not loaded from database.

You can try to use **Eagerly Loading** before you pass the data to the view. Or **Explicitly Loading** of `Employees` for specific entry (visa). If that won't work, then probably you have broken relationships in your model. Try to reconfigure the model in `OnModelCreating` method inside the `InfoDBContext` class.

Check this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data

Comment: Hi, thanks, wait... let me check and get back to you.

Comment: Try `InfoContext.Visas.Include(_ => _.Employees).Where(...).FirstOrDefault().Employees`

Comment: @Mika Kaskun: please check the updated question. As per your suggestion, i tried but not working.

Comment: returns empty for both entities

Comment: Try ToList()? `var employees = InfoContext.Visas.Include(_ => _.Employees).Where(...).FirstOrDefault().Employees.ToList()`

Answer (score 1):

`Info` navigation property in your `Visa` model class is not configured correctly. You referenced both single `Info` and `List<Info>` which does not make sense. it should be either `Info` or `List<Info>`. But according to your model classes structures it seems it should be `List<Info>` as follows:

```
public class Visa
{
    public int VisaID { get; set; }
    public string VisaName { get; set; }

    public List<Info> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Then write your `VEmployees` method as follows:

```
public ActionResult VEmployees() 
{
        InfoDBContext infoContext = new InfoDBContext();

        List<Visa> vEmployees = infoContext.Visas.Include(e => e.Employees).Where(v => v.VisaName == "Hunain").ToList();
        return View(vEmployees);
 }
```

Now everything should work fine!

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense? `EmployeeInfo` could perfectly well be the owner (or applicant, or whatever) of a `Visa` that *applies* to other employees. I think it's better to ask first.

Comment: @yes! It can be! then you have to configure the relationship properly!